# Python VTK: remove an actor from a scene with multiple actors

Tags: python, vtk

I'm new in vtk, I'm trying to learn and for this I ask for help.
I looked for a similar problem but I didn't find anything about it.

In my project (python 2.7 and VTK 6.3) I visualize several actors (from STL files) that are loaded one at a time(`self.renderer.AddActor` (`self.Actor`))

I also insert them in arrays (`self.pieces`) and display them in a `wx.ListBox` (`self.workplateList`) for list, selection, file name ...

So far so good I'm able to manage selections, changes, additions, actor operations but the problem is when I try to remove an actor:

From button I would like to delete the actor selected in the ListBox from the scene with the function:

```
def onRemoveModel(self, event):
    actor = self.pieces[self.workplateList.GetSelection()]
    self.renderer.RemoveActor[actor]
```

but returns the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File ".\main.py", line 276, in onRemoveModel
>       self.renderer.RemoveActor[actor]
>   TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Can you tell me where I'm wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Coud you provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  concerning your issue? As far as I see, I would say that it is purely a Python error and it's not related to VTK. I guess that `RemoveActor` is a method and instead you use the square bracket.

Comment: ops, very stupid mistake, thanks

Comment: You’re welcome!